# Mule: forward GET request with query parameters as POST request with json body

Tags: mule

My app receive GET requests with URL query parameters. I would like to transfer this request to another app as POST request. I want that the query parameters will appear in the POST request inside the body as json.

Input GET url for example: `http://localhost:8081/?name=John&age=30&gender=male`

Expected POST json payload: `{"name":"John", "age":30, "gender":"male"}`

I think that I should use 'Data Mapper' for that, yet I failed to do so. 
In the 'input' section I define the source to be - `Inbound Property - http.query.params` and type `Map<String,String>`. 
In the output section I want the type to be `json`.

I can't debug/print the result of this mapping so I can't see what is the outcome of my definition. Is this the correct definition?
How do I define the parameters from the URL to be inserted into the map and be transformed into json?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use DataMapper for such a simple transformation. Instead use a MEL expression transformer to create a map out of the query parameters, then add an `object-to-json-transformer` to serialize this map to JSON.

For example, this creates a map with the 'name' query param in it:

```
<expression-transformer
     expression="#[['name':message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]]" />
```

Just add all the params.